# How to add method to System.Console class in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, methods

I have little experience with Visual Basic.

I would like to add some methods to the System.Console class for a simple console application I am making. I am aware of the way to add [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to class. I've tried this code, but it gives the error: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module Module1

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub WriteStuff(ByRef Console As System.Console, ByVal Output As String)

        Console.Write(Output & "?")

    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteStuff("Hello")
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods are instance methods; they cannot be applied statically.  `System.Console` is a class, not an object, and methods like `ReadKey()` are static.  Static extension methods are not allowed.

Look at your signature:

```
Public Sub WriteStuff(ByRef Console As System.Console, ...
```

It makes no sense to take a class identifier by reference, right (or at all for that matter)?

Comment: It didn't make much sense at the time. However, the link I referenced was the only information I could find on it, so I tried it.

Comment: Ultimately, though, adding methods to classes is impossible, correct?

The information I had found had seemed slightly off from my needs, and this explains why. I had confused class methods with object methods. Thanks.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu: If they link mentioned "adding methods to a class" they likely meant "adding methods to a class definition", not "adding static methods".